# Flutter: Reset image

Tags: image, flutter

The image is still there after being added, the image is still input. How to reset the image if it has been added?

```
new Container(
  height: 100.0,
  width: 100.0,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
     border: new Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
  ),
  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
  child: image == null ? Text('Add') : Image.file(image),
),
```

Navigation to move pages using:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset your image inside `initState`

```
var file;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    file=null;
  }
```